# Service Bus or Queue Processing

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-storage-queues

Probably a stupid question.

Generally what is the best approach to have a program listening to an MQTT feed (done), placing messages onto a queue or service bus and then have those automated processed via Azure?

How would I process the messages on a queue? Is there a way for some Azure function/feature to automatically then put that into a storage account and a database after some manipulation? Generally what's the best approach? Ideally using C#.

1. Feed listens for data feeds (done)
2. Puts message onto queue or service bus (easily done)
3. Something on Azure will take that item and put it on a Storage Account and Cosmos database. (stuck on best appoach)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a message no a Service Bus Queue or Storage Account Queue. Both provide bindinds for Azure Functions, which would be the consumer. Also using Azure functions, you can use output bindings and persist to Storage Account (blob) or Cosmos DB.

Here are useful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

Comment: So when a queue receives an item, it will then fire off to a azure function for me to do my required work? Sounds too simple!

Comment: that's it. Your azure function will be triggered whenever a new message appears in your queue